# throw exception when row exist in database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, try-catch

I want to insert all the dataframe in database df. If there is duplicated row. I want to to insert some elements of this row in another table of the logs. 
Does anyone knows how to do please?
I have tried the code below: i didn't succed to catch the error

```py
#When i created my database df i put an UNIQUE key(element1, element2) So in my dataframe if i have two rows where (element1 in row i = element1 row i+1) and (element2 in row i = element2 row i+1) it is considered as duplicated.
try:
    df.to_sql(con=cnx, name='df', if_exists='append', index=False)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    logs = [df[0], df[1], 'INSERT', 'FAIl', str(err)]
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT IGNORE INTO logtable (id, element, action, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (logs))
```

Comment: According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql, `df.to_sql` seems to raise `ValueError`.

Comment: Only if `if_exists='fail'` or default. But you set the flag `if_exists='append'`, so I think the error never occurs.

Comment: @BoseongChoi thank you for your response. But this param refers to the table . I want to do aan append to the existing tables . The error is when the row exist

Comment: Oh I get it. You can use `except Exception` first, and figure out what type of exception occured.

Comment: Original post edited: please have a look

Comment: i did'nt understand, what do you mean please. ? @BoseongChoi

Comment: I have not used `df.to_sql` so I guess `mysql.connector.Error` might mismatched actual exception.

Comment: Which library do you use to insert dataframe in dabase?

Comment: I reproduced your case with `SQLAlchemy`. Which is yours?

Comment: same @BoseongChoi from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Comment: Did you added unique constraint for fields? Then you might meet an exception: `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed:`

Comment: `sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError` is root of SQLAlchemy's excpetions. I don't know where does `mysql.connector.Error` in your code come from.

Comment: If you don't want to ignore the duplicate, don't IGNORE the duplicate key.